# How to extract values from json which has multiple hierarchies inside using Python

Tags: python, json, extract

Below is the json content, how to extract values for "GBL_ACTIVE_CPU" using python.

```
{
        "test": "00.00.004",
        "Metric Payload": [
            {
                "ClassName": "test",
                "SystemId": "test",
                "uri": "http://test/testmet",
                "MetaData": [
                    {
                        "FieldName": "GBL_ACTIVE_CPU",
                        "DataType": "STRING",
                        "Label": "test",
                        "Unit": "string"
                    }
                ],
                "Instances": [
                    {
                        "InstanceNo": "0",
                        "GBL_ACTIVE_CPU": "4"
                    }
                ]
        ]               
}
```

I tried below code, but doesn't work. Any help is appreciated:

```
result = json.loads(jsonoutput)
print(result)
node = result["Metric Payload"]["Instances"]["GBL_ACTIVE_CPU"]
print(node)
```

I get below error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: Remove the stray brace on line 4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In **JSON** "**Instances**" is a list. You are accessing it like a dict. So it have 2 ways on is static other is dynamic.

If you like to use static way:-

```
result = json.loads(jsonoutput)
print(result)
node = result["Metric Payload"][0]["Instances"][0]["GBL_ACTIVE_CPU"]
print(node)
```

If you like to use dynamic way:-

```
result = json.loads(jsonoutput)
print(result)
for metric in result["Metric Payload"]: 
    for inst in metric["Instances"]:
        node = inst["GBL_ACTIVE_CPU"]
        print(node)
```

Comment: Thanks for poiinting it out. Below one worked:
node = result["Metric Payload"][0]["Instances"][0]["GBL_SYSTEM_ID"]

Here, observe [0] after [Metric Payload]. Without this, it doesn't work. I believe, as Metric payload also is a list we need to have the index for it as well.